# Find string within a list of characters in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of 9 characters which from the beginning is empty:

```
List<char> myList = new List<char>() { '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-' };
```

Then a user will input a letter on a certain position, which is given. Then the list will then look like this:

{'-', 'a', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'}

I now want to find the string that is created from each time a new letter is added. So if the list looks like this after a while:

{'-', 'a', '-', '-', 'b', '-', 'c', 'd', '-'}

And a user adds a letter on index 6 it will look like this:

{'-', 'a', '-', '-', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'd', '-'}

So I now want to output the string "becd".

One way I found is to loop through the list in each "direction" from where the letter is added and find when there is a '-' char and stop. Then the same in the other direction. Then I can merge the letters between the start and end index.

Is there an easier and cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Is the TLDR of your question "Given an array of N chars, get a list of strings built from all contiguous non-hyphen char sequences of length 4 or more" ?

Comment: Why is the output `becd`? Why is `a` not included? What would the string be in the second step -- `cd`? `abcd`? Nothing? If you have something that "works", posting existing code would immediately clarify the logic.

Comment: I think it's related to the new input, so more like - "Given an array of N chars, get the string built from the contiguous non-hyphen char sequence including a specific index."

Comment: @JeroenMostert, it is just necessary to look at the recent added letter and create the longest string possible from this index.

Comment: I think your suggested solution is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One way I found is to loop through the list in each "direction" from where the letter is added and find when there is a '-' char and stop. Then the same in the other direction. Then I can merge the letters between the start and end index.

Seems reasonable to me. As a `List<char> chars` that might look like:

```
var putAt = 6;

string.Concat(chars.Skip(chars.LastIndexOf('-', putAt) + 1).TakeWhile(c => c != '-'));
```

LastIndexOf starts at the put char (or could be put char -1 for a tiny optimization) and seeks left looking for a '-'. LINQ then skips the chars up to/including that point and takes chars rightwards while it doesn't encounter a '-'. string.Concat makes the string

If chars was an array you could do it with a range:

```
new string(
  chars[(Array.LastIndexOf(chars, '-', putAt) + 1)..Array.IndexOf(chars, '-', putAt)]
);
```

I'd expect it to be more performant, but I haven't checked - again LastIndexOf does a leftwards crawl and IndexOf does a rightwards one. This gives two indexes for the range operation that cuts a chunk of chars out of the array. String's constructor takes the new charray and makes it a string

Comment: This seems reasonable and what I asked for. Shorter than my 10 lines of codes to do the same job. Thank you!